# 吸 read ji or jie?

Tags: pronunciation, topolect

I know in some dialects of Southwestern Mandarin 吸 is read `ji` or `jie`. This is most likely due to the fact that 吸 is made up of 口 + 及 and 及 is read `ji` or `jie` in these same topolects.

Does this phenomenon occur in any other Sinitic topolects? I know, for instance, that 酝酿 read `wen rang` is common through a few different languages. So it may be that 吸, `ji` or `jie` is also common at the grassroots.

Ideas?

Comment: The correct way to say it is xi Not all Chinese characters pronounce the same without the partial parts。
Some may apply to traditional Chinese characters

Comment: Which dialects?

Comment: @AurusHuang 岷江片 for sure

Comment: [https://www.zdic.net/hans/吸](https://www.zdic.net/hans/吸)        And [https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAwNTMx](https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAwNTMx)

Comment: While some of the pronunciations of the standard Chinese word can be traced back to the root of writing, not the dialects, for which the pronunciation deviates from the standard largely due to regional reasons, and is difficult to track.  For instance, Taiwanese pronounces "吃" as "甲 (write as 口+甲), and Shanghainese pronounces "人" as "寧", any base for that, any other dialect pronounces the same way? The questions may only be answered by the local dialect enthusiasts. It is as absurd as asking if the Southern dialect in the US has anything to do with the origin of the English letters.

Answer (score 1):

This seems likely to have come from [Xiang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiang_Chinese):

---

Page 216 of《湘方言语音研究》has the following entry:

> [image]

Where we have the pronunciation and character:

> tɕi⁴⁵ 吸

Here, tɕi would equate to "ji," in simple romanization.

---

[Wiktionary | 吸](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%90%B8) has similar information:

> **Pronunciation**
>
> - Xiang (Wiktionary): ji6

> - **Dialectal data**:
>
> | Xiang | 吸 |
> | --- | --- |
> | Changsha | /t͡ɕi²⁴/ |
> | Xiangtan | /t͡ɕi²⁴/ |

---

Wiktionary does also mention:

> Chengdu    /t͡ɕi³¹/

and

> Guiyang    /t͡ɕi²¹/ 老

Under the historical backdrop of 湖广填川 it would seem likely that Hunanese migrants brought pronunciations like these West with them.

Comment: The page linked below profs that 湖南人 pronounces 吸 as 及 if ji6 = ji6, but I still don't understand what is the case you are making or trying to correlate to. The ancient Chinese migration pattern does not fit your description - Han from the North (Yellow River) towards South (Yangzi River) and settled in the Central. The South West and West were mostly occupied by the ethnic minorities that some of them were one-time enemies of the traditional Han people (漢人). I have no clue that 湖南人 had any time in history migrated further South or West, except the forced settlement during Cultural Revolution.

Comment: Link - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8F%8A

Comment: Just find out ji6 seems to encompass a group of words that differ from ji2. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ji6 You can find out the words associated with ji2 by typing it in the search box of the linked page.

Comment: @r13 In the question I simply stated that I am familiar with some local topolects where 吸 is read ji and/or jie. My question asked, "Does this happen anywhere else?" That was it. There is nothing else to read into the question.

Comment: I don't have a problem with any question unless it is misleading or derogative. Originally I had no desire to answer your question as the way it was asked sounded ridiculous and not meaningful, until the tipping point. I think you still didn't get it.

Answer (score -3):

吸 reads xi correctly.

> Not all Chinese characters pronounce the same without the partial parts

Sometimes, grass roots do pronounce characters they don't know well with the partial parts, and sometimes it's wrong. However, "吸" is a very common character in Chinese. Kids will know words like "吸管"(straw) "呼吸"(breathe) at a very young age, even before they know the character"及".

Comment: 答非所问…Not what the question asked

Answer (score -4):

I suggest checking a Chinese dictionary for a word's correct pronunciation and find out the root reason for its sound rather than randomly picking a local dialect then thinking it is the common case. No, the pronunciation is not common besides the local you stated (if it is the case), nor it is so pronounced because the word contains the word "及", although it could be the case for the words "圾", as in "垃圾[lā jī]" (note it is also pronounced as [lè sè]", and "級[jí]".

By the way, the pronunciation for "酝酿" is [yùn niàng], not [wen rang].

I could be 答非所问, but it is understandable consider your question can be described as "不知所云".

Comment: The question was asking whether there are any other dialects that pronounce it is ji or jie, not if that is the correct way to pronounce it in standard Mandarin. It's quite obvious op knows the standard pronunciation of the character.

Comment: @Curiosity Provide your example. My answer was very clear to the point - there is no such pronunciation nor such connection, the OP has no clue what he was asking, nor do you.

Comment: Note, I voted to close this post for the arrogance of the OP in commenting one of the answer providers.

Comment: "there is no such pronunciation nor such connection" just to clarify, are you asserting that there are no local dialects anywhere in China that pronounce 吸 as ji or jie?

Comment: @Curiosity Not I am aware of. I think you have a reading comprehension problem - 不求甚解. Please read the entire thread to see where my answer/comments came about. We are wasting time on this non-sense

Comment: "Does this phenomenon occur in any other Sinitic topolects?" This is literally the op's question. No part of your answer addressed the question or is even tangentially relevant, it adds nothing to help the op or future readers of this site. Considering you called the question "不知所云" when it's perfectly clear, you should really think twice before commenting on others' reading comprehension.

Comment: Again, you are "以偏概全". Did you read the other answers and comments made by the OP? That's what I wanted to ridicule - don't appreciate others' effort in coming up a just answer.

Comment: My harsh words are just a return of favors.

Comment: The OP was clearly asking for the pronunciation of 吸 in a dialect. By making such a comment "My answer was very clear to the point - there is no such pronunciation", are you claiming you know ALL the dialects in China?

Comment: @joehua First, read the answer provided by member "ly z" and the sole comment below (by the OP). Then look at my answer. Sofar everybody has responded with a common answer - "there is no such pronunciation as far as we are aware of", but he was rude/arrogant towards the responder, I consider it is a very despicable attitude by the OP on a language forum like this, thus my harsh response.

Comment: @joehua Note the OP has revised the comment, originally there was only the 答非所问, no english.

Comment: @r13 "thus my harsh response" I wasn't talking about your harsh response. I was talking about your illogical response. The fact that you don't know doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Unless you know ALL the Chinese dialects, how can you claim such  pronunciation doesn't exist? This is illogical. Now that the OP has provided two references in which 吸 pronounces as ji, do you still claim such a pronunciation doesn't exist?

Comment: @joehua Co-incidence has no meaning nor value for language learning. Didn't you read the whole thing, including the comments?

Comment: @r13 If you want to reply, please reply to the following question only. Do not mention anything else. "If you don't know ALL the Chinese dialects, how can you claim there is no such pronunciation?"

Comment: @joehua I didn't have the desire to answer until seeing the comment on "ly z's" answer by the OP. It wasn't an answer, period.

Comment: Besides other mistakes, the correlation made between the dialect at locals around Ming River is very weak as the watershed of Ming River wasn't even the territory of China. The latter correlation to Xiang (湘) is also questionable as I have commented on it. You can downvote the answer, but you can't downplay the fact. If you know anything that can dispute my answer, provide your examples, otherwise do some researches. We don't need to be a linguist to know something simply does not make sense.